# I can't install snaps

Tags: firefox, vlc, snap

According to snapcraft website vlc, Firefox are available as a snap format

https://snapcraft.io/vlc
https://snapcraft.io/firefox

but when I try to install any of them via the command line they couldn't be installed does anyone have any fixes for this

```
yousef@yousef-G31M-ES2L:~$ sudo apt-get install snapd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
snapd is already the newest version (2.32.9).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
yousef@yousef-G31M-ES2L:~$ sudo snap install firefox
error: snap "firefox" not found
yousef@yousef-G31M-ES2L:~$ sudo snap install vlc
error: snap "vlc" not found
```

This is my system information:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apps you are trying to install are 64-bit applications but you use a 32-bit OS, that's the reason why you can't install them. Your machine should be able to run 64-bit-OS though.

Comment: are you sure 
I checked telegram desktop on snap store and found only amd64 variant only of this app and I could successfully find it 

https://snapcraft.io/telegram-desktop

why I can't find the other apps like firefox and VLC ??

(yousef@yousef-G31M-ES2L:~$ sudo snap find telegram-desktop
Name              Version  Developer  Notes  Summary
telegram-desktop  1.3.0    3v1n0      -      Official desktop client for the Telegram messenger)

Comment: the same happens with gnome-calculator I can install it and run it with no problems although it only has amd64 variant ??

https://snapcraft.io/gnome-calculator

Comment: If you can install and run an application on a 32-bit-system the application is definitely a 32-bit-application. I don't think that *snapcraft.io* is up to date, use `snap find` to see if an application for your platform exists.

Comment: you are right I updated my system to 64 bit and now I can install snaps

Comment: @YousefSaber Please click the gray checkmark beside this answer to mark it as accepted. The checkmark will change colors from gray to green when it is clicked.